# custom mozilla addon: how to install?

Tags: firefox-addon

I created a simple mozilla addon. Debugging is fine - all works. Now I want to install it and have problems. I know Im supposed to create install.rdf, but cant do this. I need it as minimum as possible - addon will work only on 4 PC's at the office.

My files:
/icons
- background.js
- manifest.json

Can You help?

Answer (score 0):

The publishing process for firefox addons varies depending on whether you want the extension to be public, unlisted, etc.

It sounds to me like you want a private extension with no web store distribution.  To do this, you will need to create a web store account and get the extension signed.

Read this about getting the extension signed:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution

That process will result in a signed extension that you can then privately distribute however you choose.

Packaging is detailed at 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Publishing_your_WebExtension#2._Create_an_account_on_addons.mozilla.org